# entropy transfer v. work transfer

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, work

Are there any work transfer mechanisms that cannot transfer entropy and if so why? What are the general theoretical limitations on entropy transfer from one system to another? By system I do not just mean volumetrically closed ones; I am also thinking of, say, entropy exchange between the electron gas and the surrounding crystal lattice.

Comment: You are talking about work and entropy transfer in an open system, correct?  Are you familiar with the control volume (open system) versions of the energy balance equation (first law of thermodynamics) and entropy balance equation?

Comment: What do you have in mind when when you say a "work transfer mechanism"? A reversible adiabtic process does work and transfers no entropy, so does that count? or does that not count because I could expand the gass irreversibly if I wanted to?

Comment: @BySymmetry I did not mean that way. Take for example a magnetocaloric material; one can adiabatically bias the crystal via an induction coil (work from a battery) and thereby heat it up, but when you remove the bias and cool it can you capture and transfer the demagnetization excess entropy via induction into a resistive load? Can magnetic work via induction carry entropy out of the system?

Comment: @ChesterMiller yes, I am thinking of an open system, please, see above comment.

Comment: Work does not transfer entropy. In the crystal example you quote, electrical work transfers energy to the crystal, but not entropy. Entropy is generated inside the crystal system by electrical resistance, not transferred from the battery.

Comment: @user1476176 I think you are mistaken about this, please, see section, for example "Thermodynamics Cycle" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration

Comment: I assume you are talking about the way the "Adiabatic magnetization" step is described. That section states that magnetic entropy is decreased but "total entropy is not reduced (according to thermodynamic laws)." I should correct my previous comment and say that *ideally* the process could be reversible, in which case there would be no entropy generation, but this would not change the fact that the work does not transfer entropy. The reason that the temperature increases even in the ideal case is that the system's internal energy is rearranged so that more of it is sensible thermal energy.

Comment: Look up the entropy transport equation - you will see that there is no transfer term associated with work, and in fact that the work does not appear *anywhere* in it. If work could transport entropy, the entropy transport equation would need to have a work-related term to capture that effect.

Comment: @user1476176 I did not say that work makes entropy move, what I asked if there is a work transfer mechanism that cannot  be associated with entropy transfer. In this context the question is if it is possible to capture the entropy of the spins via magnetic induction before they equilibrate with the lattice? This has nothing to do with being reversible. Another example: a coaxial transmission line with matching loads on either end but at different temperature. They will equilibrate, see Nyquist noise. Break the coax, reconnect with a transformer; could they equilibrate via inductive coupling?

Comment: Your original question, and now your comments, seem to branch out into a lot of directions. I think the question as written would be difficult to answer because (1) there is so much going on and (2) to me, everything after the first sentence of the question is moot because work can never transfer entropy. I suggest that you edit your question to focus on what you mean by this first sentence and to discuss only one example process, including details like what it means to you to "transfer" entropy and where the energy and entropy are coming from and going to in your analysis.

Comment: @user1476176 of course work can transfer entropy, move anything that has any non-zero mass and has positive absolute temperature.

Comment: In control volume analysis that would be classified as entropy transfer by *advection* - entropy moving because matter is moving - rather than by work. The work doesn't directly transfer entropy; it moves the matter which carries the entropy.