# Entropy of electricity and heat

Tags: entropy

Is it correct to say that a MW hour of electrical energy delivered has less entropy  than  a MW hour ( 3.6 GJ) of  process heat delivered, for example, in the form of steam?

Comment: Do you know the difference between entropy transfer and entropy generation? The difference between reversible and irreversible heat and work?

Answer (score 2):

Entropy change potentially consists of two components: entropy transferred plus entropy generated. Only heat transfers entropy. Work (including electrical work) does not transfer entropy. On the other hand both heat and work, if irreversible, generates entropy.

For the energy transfer to be reversible, the rate of energy transfer must be very low (power approaching zero). The rate of energy transfer in your examples (1 MJ/s) certainly does not approach zero. So both processes are irreversible and generate entropy.

However, since only heat transfers entropy and work does not, one would expect that the total entropy change due to irreversible electrical work would be less than the total entropy change for irreversible heat transfer, for the same amount of energy transfer (3.6 GJ).

Hope this helps.

Comment: bulk movement of any ponderable matter moves everything inside it including mass, entropy, internal energy, polarization, etc. Electric current does carry entropy because the electrons have temperature dependent random motion imposed on their drift velocity.

Comment: @hyportnex So you are saying all forms of work (electrical, flow work, boundary work, turbine work) transfers entropy, or is it unique to electrical work. It has always been my understanding that in thermodynamics, work does not transfer entropy, though it can generate entropy.

Comment: I did not say *all* work transfers entropy, only that work involving bulk movement does change the physical location of whatever entropy it has. A pint of beer has entropy and moving form here to there takes work on my part and that work moves everything that is in the pint. Actually, couple of years ago I asked a question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437841/entropy-transfer-v-work-transfer if there is work process that does not not transfer entropy. I still do not think I got a satisfying answer and calling it "advection" does not resolve the issue.

Comment: I was wondering if, for example, an ideal transformer, $V_1I_1=V_2I_2$, $V_2=nV_1; I_1=nI_2$ can pass entropy from its primary to its secondary, say between two resistors starting at different temperatures but not connected to thermostats. On the warmer side the Johnson-Nyquist noise (random voltage/current, $<v^2>=2Rk_BT$) is stronger than on the colder side. Would they equalize their temperatures and if yes how?

Comment: @hyportnex Interesting points, but if we continue it should probably be in Chat.

Comment: I will be happy to, this question has been bothering me for a while...

Comment: How about we invite Chet Miller to participate? He is an excellent resource.

Comment: great idea, though he was not much impressed by my question a couple of years ago.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117745/discussion-between-bob-d-and-hyportnex).

Comment: @Chet Miller We would appreciate it if you would join us. I think the topic requires someone with deep knowledge in thermodynamics.

Comment: So to summarize, I understand it is NOT correct to say that electricity  has entropy ( compared to say a fluid) because electricity has no "temperature". This is true at a macro level /classical physics , however at a micro level considering individual electron movement  it could be considered to have entropy. Have I got that right - basically?